# Преобразование ДатаВремя из Delphi в Java

Tags: java, delphi

Никак не могу сообразить как можно перевести датавремя из делфи (в виде double) в Java, чтобы привести к виду `LocalDateTime` Java. Отсчёт в делфи идёт с `1899-12-30 12:00AM` (т.е. 00:00 по нашему, спасибо [zed](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/177722/zed) за исправление).
Так как можно преобразовать с минимальными расчётами значение и получить читабельный для юзеров результат.

И так, возьмем для примера следующее число:

```
45070.381944444445
```

Если с `45070` это понятно, что это 24 мая 2023 года, то `381944444445` остается для меня загадкой, объясните чайнику, пожалуйста.

Comment: `45070.381944444445` из Delphi в формате TDateTime это `24.05.2023 9:10:00`. Проверить это можно используя метод из Delphi `DateTimeToStr`

Comment: если округлить следующим образом `45070.38195`, то результат будет тем же `24.05.2023 9:10:00`, только вот если к последнему прибавить `0.00001`, т.е. получить `45070.38196`, то результатом будет `24.05.2023 9:10:01`

Comment: Вот, в делфи то получить это я могу, а как мне получить эту же дату в Java?

Comment: `0.381944444445 * 24*60*60*1000` - количество миллисекунд с начала дня.

Comment: Большое спасибо @zed

Comment: И кстати, отсчёт времени Delphi ведёт с 1899-12-30 12:00 **A.M.**, что по нашему с `1899-12-30 00:00`

Comment: Исправил в описании, спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решение задачи выполняется следующим образом, с использованием нулевого часового пояса.

```
    //Устанавливаем нулевую дату отсчёта для даты
    LocalDate zeroDate = LocalDate.of(1899, 12, 30);

    //Формула предоставленная @zed (или 86400000 мс)
    long ms = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;

    //Дата в формате делфи
    double firstdate = 45070.381944444445;

    //Получаем целевую дату
    LocalDate targetDate = zeroDate.plusDays((int) firstdate);

    //Умножаем оставшуюся без даты разницу на формулу
    double gettime = (firstdate - (int) firstdate) * ms;

    //Получаем время с часовым поясом +00:00
    TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("0"));
    Time time = new Time((long) gettime);

    //Преобразовываем в формат ДатаВремя
    LocalDateTime localDateTime = targetDate.atTime(time.toLocalTime());
```

Вывод получаем в виде `2023-05-24T09:10`.
Естественно всё можно упростить, все расписал для большей наглядности решения.